# How to fill in tab backgrounds for the UI Bootstrap tab directive?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the UI Bootstrap tab (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) on my webiste but its style seems a bit unfinished.

So I completed the bordered box on the bottom so it looks like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wq3vTkR3CqQQSmG9gbW1?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">   
        a:focus {
            outline: none;
        }                
    </style>    
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl" style="padding: 20px">

  <tabset justified="true">
    <tab heading="Info 1"><div style="border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; padding: 10px">Justified content</div></tab>
    <tab heading="SJ"><div style="border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; padding: 10px">2222</div></tab>
    <tab heading="Long Justified"><div style="border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; padding: 10px">3333</div></tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But now:

- how do I get rid of the thick 2px line at the bottom of the tabs on top of the content?

[image]

- how do I set the non-active tabs to have backgrounds like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix this using `ui-bootstrap` need to add some styles that will overwrite default styling:

See the [**example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SJMTuEK1PEjtcnDAsaWt?p=preview)

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
  margin-left: 2px ;
  top: 1px;
  border: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li:first-child > a {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a:link {
  background: #eee;
}
```

> This should works well, but... this option should not be recommended, because if new update for `ui-bootstrap` library will come, then your styling may crash and manual update will be necessary)

Instead of that, you may consider to use [`angular-strap`](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads#tabs), it seams to be more stable in production then `ui-bootstrap` in these days (the day of writing this answer).